# How to program a kind of auto correction for inputs?

Tags: javascript, search, input

I got some nodes with different names, let's say one of them is:

"Max Wil"

Now, i am able to use an input and type in the name of the node i am looking for and check if the input is equal witht he name of the node:

```
 if(d.name.toLowerCase() == inputValue.toLowerCase())
```

In the case of "Max Wil" i have to make an correct input with the spacebar. Now i want to know if there is a kind of auto correction that allows me to only put in "Max" and the program makes a suggestion for the available node named "Max Wil"? I want a kind of stuff you can do when search for words in Google.

Comment: You mean autocomplete? Plenty of libraries out there.

Comment: yap, autocomplete

Comment: So pick a library....

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist